# R Shiny observe only a specific reactiveVal change

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Is it possible to have an `observe` function fire only when a specific `reactiveVal` changes?

In my all-over-the-code cross-referencing modules with reactives and observers, I have something that boils down to the following toy example:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    textInput('i1', 'Input 1'),
    textInput('i2', 'Input 2'),
    textInput('out', 'Output (do not edit)')
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    observe({ print(input$i2); updateTextInput(session, 'out', value = input$i1) })
    observe({ print(input$i1); updateTextInput(session, 'out', value = input$i2) })
  }
)
```

Notice that without the print statements, the code would work as I would want it to work. However, if both observers make use of both inputs, both fire sequentially and only `input$i2` from the second observer is put into my `out` textInput.

Is there some way for me to tell shiny that I only want the first `observe` to run when `input$i1` changes, and the second `observe` to run when `input$i2` changes?

## EDIT

Turns out you can just use `observeEvent` on inputs to distinguish between those. However, in a now more convoluted example, I'm not able to use `observeEvent` on `reactiveVal` - in that case it doesn't fire at all. Again, the following example works without the print statement, but with it both observers fire.

Is there a way to observe changes in a `reactiveVal`?

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    textInput('i1', 'Make uppercase'),
    textInput('i2', 'Make lowercase'),
    textInput('out', 'Output (ideally not editable)')
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    i1 <- reactiveVal('')
    i2 <- reactiveVal('')

    observeEvent(input$i1, { i1(toupper(input$i1)) })
    observeEvent(input$i2, { i2(tolower(input$i2)) })

    observe({ print(i2()); updateTextInput(session, 'out', value = i1()) })
    observe({ print(i1()); updateTextInput(session, 'out', value = i2()) })
  }
)
```

Comment: `observeEvent(input$i1, {...})`

Comment: Huh... I could swear that I've tried it in my project but I didn't get it to work there. Guess my problem lies somewhere else. Thanks @lz100! (feel free to post your answer below)

Comment: @lz100 Ok I think I got the part of the program that causes the problem - `observeEvent` does not work on `reactiveVal`. See my edit - is there any way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`observeEvent` does work with any reactive context, here is the example how it works with `reactiveVal`

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    textInput('i1', 'Make uppercase'),
    textInput('i2', 'Make lowercase'),
    textInput('out', 'Output (ideally not editable)')
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    i1 <- reactiveVal('')
    i2 <- reactiveVal('')
    
    observeEvent(input$i1, { i1(toupper(input$i1)) })
    observeEvent(input$i2, { i2(tolower(input$i2)) })
    
    observeEvent(i1(), {print(i2()); updateTextInput(session, 'out', value = i1()) })
    observeEvent(i2(), {print(i1()); updateTextInput(session, 'out', value = i2()) })
  }
)
```

Comment: Awesome! In previous attempts with `observeEvent` I was always missing the braces `()` after the reactive value `i1()` and `i2()`